# Elasticsearch - '127.0.0.1:9200' and 'localhost:9200' are unable to connect on the browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, browser, elasticsearch, virtual-machine

When I try curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200' on my terminal it is working fine.[image]

But, When I try http://localhost:9200/ or 127.0.0.1:9200/ on my browser it shows[image]

How can I fix this problem ?

Comment: What's the browser are you using? If you are using IE you need to write "http://" before address.

Comment: I can see you're using Vagrant right? On the command line you are on the virtual machine. Your browser is on the virtual machine too? If not you need to use the virtual machine IP to access elastic search.

Comment: Yes, I am using Vagrant and I am using my normal browser on my mac. So how can I get the virtual machine IP to access elastic search on my browser ?

Comment: You can execute "ifconfig" on virtual machine command line to get its IP.

Comment: I am not understand what is the problem, because I am using curl -XGET http://localhost:9200 and curl -XGET 127.0.0.1:9200 on terminal it is working fine, but when I use these address on my browser are not working.

Comment: But you are using curl on virtual machine's terminal probably connected via ssh.

Answer (score 4):

I understand it is too late to answer, but "late" is relative.

As you are using curl in virtual machine, where elasticsearch is running, it is returning result in terminal. But to see it in the browser of the parent OS,
You need to do this:

- Get the ip address of the linux machine where elasticsearch is running. (ifconfig), let's say it is 10.75.108.136
- Now open elasticsearch.yml in config directory and change below two properties
  a. network.host: "linux virtual machine ipaddress"
  b. uncomment http.port: 9200
- start elasticsearch
- In Parent OS go to http://10.75.108.136:9200/

:)